# converting coordinates to address v3 google api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not able to convert my coordinates to address ...
Almost got adjusting function below ... but how many markers are, just creating only the last marker ...:

My function to create markers:

```
    function createMarker(point,info,map) {
    var iconURL = 'img/pata.png';               
    var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(32,34);
    var iconOrigin = new google.maps.Point(0,0);    
    var iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(15,30);

    var myIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconURL, iconSize, iconOrigin, iconAnchor);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : point,
      html : info,
      map : map,
      icon: myIcon
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Dispositivo: " + info + "<br> Endereço: " + point

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,this);
      });

  }
```

My function to create bookmarks:
Function that was trying to adapt (just wanted to send the coordinates and he convert to address and leave the infowindow when clicking)

```
    function codeLatLng() {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could,

but do not know how to get the addresses separately to list ...
but got the click infowindow:

```
function createMarkerAtual(point,info,dt,map) {
    var iconURL = 'img/dog2.png';               
    var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(45,45);
    var iconOrigin = new google.maps.Point(0,0);    
    var iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(15,30);

    var myIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconURL, iconSize, iconOrigin, iconAnchor);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : point,
      html : info,
      map : map,
      icon: myIcon
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        endereco(info,this.position);
        infowindow.open(map,this);
    });

  } 

function endereco(info,point){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': point}, function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            infowindow.setContent('<b>Coordenadas: </b>' + point + '<br><b>Dispositivo:</b> ' + info + '<br><b>Endereço: </b>' + results[0].formatted_address);
        } else {

        }
    });
}
```